# Is there any way a builder can register a callback using a method of the created object?

Tags: methods, callback, closures, rust, builder

Given: the object `Foo` and `FooBuilder`. It is necessary that `FooBuilder` creates the object and registers a callback using a method of the object being created. The builder in this case acts as an advanced customization of the object `Foo` that needs to change based on the receipt of the event. A static method is not mandatory, but desirable all the same. At the end of main() is the event loop

```
 #[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::sync::Mutex;

struct Global {
    callbacks: Vec<Box<Fn(i32) + 'static + Send + Sync>>
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref GLOBAL: Mutex<Global> = {
        Mutex::new(Global {
            callbacks: Vec::new()
        })
    };
}

struct FooBuilder {
    c: i32
}
impl FooBuilder {
    fn new() -> FooBuilder {
        FooBuilder {
            c: 0
        }
    }
    fn build(&self) -> Foo {
        let foo = Foo {
            f: self.c
        };
        // foo.set_callback(|x| foo.edit());
        // ^ ERROR
        foo
    }
}
struct Foo {
    f: i32
}
impl Foo {
    fn edit(&mut self) {
        self.f += 1;
        println!("{:?}", self.f);
    }
    fn set_callback<F>(&self, f: F)
        where F: Fn(i32)  + 'static + Send + Sync {
        GLOBAL.lock().unwrap().callbacks.push(Box::new(f));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = FooBuilder::new().build();
    /* event loop */
}
```

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question. And you should further minimize your example as long as it doesn't change the error message (drop `with_{a,b}` for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not for your case.

Consider this part of your code:

```
fn set_callback<F>(&self, f: F)
    where F: Fn(i32) + 'static + Send + Sync
```

This says that any closure provided to the method can only contain references that match the `'static` lifetime. The address of your `foo` instance is only guaranteed to be valid inside the body of the `build` method, so by definition the lifetime cannot be `'static`.

If that was preventable, you are restricting your closure to `Fn` types, but you want to call a method that requires a mutable receiver.

---

What you *can* do is provide `self` to the closure and then use it there:

```
fn set_callback<F>(&self, f: F)
    where F: Fn(&mut Self, i32) + 'static + Send + Sync
{}

// Elsewhere
foo.set_callback(|foo, x| foo.edit());
```

---

From your edited comment:

> then this approach is not very suitable

The problem is that the way you are modeling the problem is fraught with peril and Rust is preventing you from shooting yourself in the foot. You can only have a single mutable reference to an item. Beyond that, you are trying to share a reference to a stack-allocated item across function calls.

Perhaps you'd be happier with a solution that is closer to what a language with garbage collection might create?

Here, we use a [`Mutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) to allow multiple threads to share a single mutable item. We use an [`Arc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) so that multiple threads can share in the ownership of the item.

I also moved `set_callback` to a free function as it has no relation to the struct that you previously had it on.

When calling `set_callback`, we clone the `Arc` which increases the reference count and give that clone to the global queue. Since the `Mutex` has *internal mutability*, the function can remain `Fn`.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::sync::{Mutex,Arc};

struct Global {
    callbacks: Vec<Box<Fn(i32) + 'static + Send + Sync>>
}

fn set_callback<F>(f: F)
    where F: Fn(i32) + 'static + Send + Sync
{
    GLOBAL.lock().unwrap().callbacks.push(Box::new(f));
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref GLOBAL: Mutex<Global> = {
        Mutex::new(Global {
            callbacks: Vec::new()
        })
    };
}

struct FooBuilder;

impl FooBuilder {
    fn build(&self) -> Arc<Mutex<Foo>> {
        let foo = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Foo));
        let inner_foo = foo.clone();
        set_callback(move |_| inner_foo.lock().unwrap().edit());
        foo
    }
}

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn edit(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let _foo = FooBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: If we consider the registration of callbacks as an external API, it is possible to make it more beautiful?